# SUM(Value) Group By After PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

I have the following query for Pivot, that works nicely.

```
WITH PivotData AS 
( 
SELECT fechaHora, idWatimetro, semana, hora, minuto,dia,mes ,ano,valor
FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM PivotData 
PIVOT(SUM(valor) FOR idWatimetro IN (
     [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]
    ) ) AS P 
order by fechaHora, semana,dia,mes;
```

[image]

But now, I must be able to get Sum(valor) for every month or days or weeks or Year, but I´m trying without success, any help will be nice

Thank you for your time.

After suggestion of Pieter Geerkens, What I want to do is like this
The Sum(1),Sum(2),Sum(3)... Sum(10) for every Month.
The Month is an example, becuase this parameter can be, Year , day or weeks
Sorry for not to be very clear, my english is not very good.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect the desired output to look like? Without this, every attempt to assist becomes a random guess on what you are looking for. Also, it is not clear that what you desire can actually be created by a single query, as it would seem to be a hierarchical result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your query but you need to alter pivot source Query by remove the columns which not needed in final result. Try this.

```
WITH PivotData
     AS (SELECT idWatimetro,
                mes,
                ano,
                valor
         FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros)
SELECT *
FROM   PivotData
       PIVOT(Sum(valor)
            FOR idWatimetro IN ( [1],
                                 [2],
                                 [3],
                                 [4],
                                 [5],
                                 [6],
                                 [7],
                                 [8],
                                 [9],
                                 [10] ) ) AS P
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second CTE to do the pivot and use the final `SELECT` to `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH PivotData AS 
( 
SELECT fechaHora, idWatimetro, semana, hora, minuto,dia,mes ,ano,valor
FROM   E_Registros_Watimetros where ano = 2012
), tempData AS (
SELECT *
FROM PivotData 
PIVOT(SUM(valor) FOR idWatimetro IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) AS P
)

SELECT MONTH(fechaHora) AS [Month],
        SUM([1]) AS KW1,
        SUM([2]) AS KW2,
        SUM([3]) AS KW3
FROM tempData
GROUP BY MONTH(fechaHora)
```

**Edit:** The above query works on my SQL Server 2008 box.

Comment: I try that but don´t work for me , for every column show the following error "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid column name '1' ... '10'

Comment: You can alias the column names in `tempData` CTE: `SELECT [1] AS KW1, [2] AS KW2, ...`

Comment: Please take a look, I don´t see any error, but don´t work, I have tried like the above code.

Comment: I will try, becuase I never use it.

Comment: With SQLServer2008 works, but by the way with SQL Server 2005 don´t works